# Xamarin Get child from ContentView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I created a custom renderer for my ContentView and uses the following code to add a label to the ContentView:

```
Label text = new Label { Text = entry.Text, TextColor = Color.FromHex(SelectedTextColor), FontSize = 30 };
draggableView.Content = text;
```

But now I want to edit the text from the label, so I need to access it again. The problem is that a ContentView doesn't have a property `Children`, so I can't access it like that.

How can I still edit the label?

Comment: expose a public property or method on your custom ContentView that will update the label's contents

Comment: I guess `Content` is the property you are looking for instead of `Children`.

Comment: No, because then I need to do something like `mContentView.Content.Text` and that is not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, the Content equals the Label, therefore you could directly access it with the Content property casted to the type Xamarin.Forms.Label:

```
Label text = new Label { Text = entry.Text, TextColor = Color.FromHex(SelectedTextColor), FontSize = 30 };
draggableView.Content = text;
((Label)draggableView.Content).Text = "my updated text";
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said, you need to create Bindable Property on your ContentView, then use this ContentView in other contentpage, binding property to Contentview's Bindable Property, then you can update the Label text in contentview by Bindable Property, I do one sample that you can take a look:

ContentView:

```
<ContentView
x:Class="demo2.simplecontrol.View1"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="label1" />
        <Entry x:Name="label2" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

```
public partial class View1 : ContentView
{
    public View1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();          
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty Label1Property= BindableProperty.Create(
                    nameof(Label1),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(View1),
        "",
        BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            if (newValue != null && bindable is View1 control)
            {
                var actualNewValue = (string)newValue;
                control.label1.Text = actualNewValue;
            }
        });

    public string Label1 { get; set; }

    public static readonly BindableProperty Label2Property = BindableProperty.Create(
                    nameof(Label2),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(View1),
        "",
        BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            if (newValue != null && bindable is View1 control)
            {
                var actualNewValue = (string)newValue;
                control.label2.Text = actualNewValue;
            }
        });

    public string Label2 { get; set; }
}
```

ContentPage:

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="demo2.simplecontrol.Page10"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:demo2.simplecontrol">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <local:View1 Label1="{Binding text1}" Label2="{Binding text2}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
public partial class Page10 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text1;
    public string text1
    {
        get { return _text1; }
        set
        {
            _text1 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("text1");
        }
    }

    private string _text2;
    public string text2
    {
        get { return _text2; }
        set
        {
            _text2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("text2");
        }
    }

   
    public Page10 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        text1 = "test1";
        text2 = "test2";
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

      
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

You can change text1 and text2 value to update Label text in Contentview.

Comment: Thanks, but a few things are different in my situation. I add the label programmatically to the Layout inside the contentview, so I don't have x:name, but I always got only 1 label in each contentview. Maybe I can access it by knowing that there is only one?